# Title in page does not change with different page of the same View

Tags: views

I have a View which displays a list of content. The content is paged, like this

```
http://www.exampple.com/en/products?product=all&brand=0&page=4
```

I keep the parameter **page** as exactly provided by default View pager. However, when clicking on different pages, the TITLE of the page does not change, it is "Products | WEBSITE_NAME" all the time. I would have expected the page number to be added automatically, as the site domain name is. For instance:

```
 "Products Page 1 of 3 | WEBSITE NAME"
```

Is there a module or a config to achieve this, or must I do it through a hook and `drupal_set_title` function in my custom module ?

The above different title for each page is necessary to avoid SEO penalization by Google and other seo bots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AJAX in your view, the title won't change. Also, try adding !1 or %1 to your view title.